# Search form for FreeForm entries

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a page displaying all FreeForm entries. Now I'd like to add a search form to search the entries. I haven't found anything in the documentation about doing this so thought I'd ask here.

I found information about show the results:

```
{exp:freeform:entries  search:name="{last_segment}" }   

    ...

{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Just not sure how to construct the search form.